# Way to Switch Between Development and Live Database with EF?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an application written in ASP.NET and using EF. I want to make a copy of the live database, have my application point to the copy, and be able to run the application against it as if it is live...but making updates to the copy.

I know I can manually copy the database and manually update the web.config files...but I'm wondering if there is a better, more automated method for achieving this with VS 2010?

Also, if there is anything I need to know about setting up a live/dev version of a database while using EF4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the `ConnectionString` to point to the live or development database.

One way is to have different web.config files for `debug` and `release` builds.

Check out [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd465326.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience,

Setup 2 database connection entries in your config file, name one backup and leave the other ones name alone. Point your backup one to the backup db and when you want to run the backup, just change the names of the entries so the backup one is the actual name and the live one is named anything else.

Also, as for setting up different db versions - I'd just be careful that you don't update live by mistake!! and I've found it best to track changes to the db structure in a sql file so the live can be updated if needed or the backup can be rolled back if changes are made